# hierarchical bar graph using flot js

Tags: flot, stackedbarseries

I've been searching for hours if the hierarchical bar graph is supported in flot but I can't find a good documentation or answer. I find some examples using multiple xaxis(xaxes) but this seems different from what I want. See image below:

[image]

Now, my question is that is this the correct approach or do I need find a new plugin to use?

Thanks!

Comment: The goal here is to group each country by year. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify: Is the image what you want to achieve? Or do you want it another way?

Comment: @Raidri - The image is what I have achieved so far. As you can see, I have another x-axis below the countries (which is year), but I think this is not the correct way to achieve this. What I need is something like this : https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-stacked-and-grouped. Is this possible in flot?